# Using PartialView to create dynamic MainMenu in _Layout Page - Asp.net core razorpage

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, razor-pages, partial-views

i want to using PartialView in My _Layout Page
and this is my PartialView code:

```
  @model List<WebApplication4.Models.MainMenuTable>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="@item.Link">@item.Title</a>
    </li>
}
```

and this is my _Layout Page code:

```
@{
    var partialModel = new List<MainMenuTable>()
    {
   
    };
}
```

and:

```
<partial name="_MainMenu" model="partialModel"/>
```

but i saw nothing in result why?

Comment: Because your `partialModel` is an empty list, so when you pass the empty list to the Partial View, and there is no item will be iterated for the `foreach` loop, thus the `foreach` loop will be skipped and nothing is rendered. Have you tried to provide at least 1 item in the `partialModel` list and see it works?

Comment: Can you give me one example for partialModel?

Comment: i Just Need to item.Link and item.Title

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, But you need to pass some data into  `Partial View` when you use it in `_Layout.cshtml`, Refer to this simple demo:

```
@{
        var partialModel = new List<MainMenuTable>()
        {
            new MainMenuTable
            {
                Title = "HomePage",
                Link = "index"
            },
            new MainMenuTable
            {
                Title = "PrivacyPage",
                Link = "Privacy"
            }
        };
    }

    <partial name="_MainMenu" model="partialModel"/>
```

[image]

When you don't pass any data into `Partival View`, It will not show in your `_Layout`.